# Is it possible to burn a Linux DVD on 2 CD discs?

Tags: windows-7, linux, dvd, burning, cd-burning

I'm on windows 7 right now. Here's the situation, I'm trying to boot Linux mint Debian Cinnamon. It's too big to fit on 1 CD, and i don't have DVDs right now. I tried booting using usb but for some reason it doesn't boot, usually it works but my PC isn't detecting it.

I have many empty CDs, so is it possible to burn it on 2 CDs? like the big Xbox games or whatever, where you insert disc one and then disc two and so one.

I already know that what I'm asking for is crazy! (to say the very least, but you could call me stupid, no hard feelings) Nonetheless, the question is within the defined FAQ.

Comment: And on the website [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php) it states "Buy CDs" so why wouldn't there be a **CD** download ;) Guess they haven't fixed the button yet.

Comment: Another option are USB drives, if the target system can boot from them.

Comment: @DavidFoerster As i stated in the question, I'm no longer able for some reason to boot from USB, I think it's because my laptop is already dualbooted, it goes directly to grub, I tried manipulating BIOS, didn't work, the only option is to use a cd/dvd

Comment: Your BIOS shouldn't care about any on-disk boot loader, before you tell it, which one to use (e. g. via a default boot order setting). Are you sure there is no override? Many BIOS have the option to press some key during BIOS stage (F8, F12, Alt+F2…) to select the boot medium.

Comment: @DavidFoerster it is F10 indeed and I set it to boot from USB, recently it is ignoring that option and proceeding to grub menu!

Comment: @Fischer - Sounds like the usb device isn't actually bootable because any attempt would be BEFORE grub is even seen.

Comment: It may also be a different issue, I don't remember the details but I had trouble booting LMDE from a USB drive on some machines. Some hardware worked with [`unetbootin`](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) others with [`multisystem`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/). Try making a USB with both tools, see if that helps. You could also install Debian testing (which comes in CD-size isos) and then point your `sources.list` to LMDE's repos and make the switch to LMDE.

Comment: Would you use this for installation of Linux on your harddrive?

Comment: @terdon I've been thinking about your suggestion, might do that or might give this a try http://aptosid.com, I've read some good reviews about it, but I hope it won't just die like fuduntu

Comment: no I changed my mind, it seems just like debian testing with a different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use two CD's to boot Linux's OS or at least split up any OS for that matter. It's not the same as a two disc video game, the game is not an operating system, XBox already has one. Think of the OS as the base of a pyramid and anything you stack on top of it is running another program (video game, iTunes, etc).

Hope this helps.